# What is the jhipster_gateway_authorized-microservices-endpoints__app1 spring property for

Tags: jhipster

I created a microservice project with a gateway & stuff, and I've some interrogation on one of the gateway spring property.

I've this one on my gateway's application-dev.yml (also prod):

```
    jhipster:
    gateway:
        authorized-microservices-endpoints:
            app1: /api,/v2/api-docs
```

I'm suspecting that the 'app1' shall be replaced by one or all my microservices (and maybe the UAA one too), but I don't know what it does.

Any description or insight on it?

Regards,

Comment: It's documented here : http://www.jhipster.tech/api-gateway/#acl

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, I already read it (without really taking care of the impacts): why app1 by default? What if I don't replace it by my uServices: the doc seems to tell that all their API is available, isn't it kind of dangerous to have this behavior by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jhipster.gateway.authorized-microservices-endpoints` config variable controls access to your microservices when requested through the gateway.  In the case of the example, only `/api` (API endpoints) and `/v2/api-docs` (Swagger docs) are accessible through the gateway for the `app1` microservice.

This means if you try to request an API mapping that is not present in the list (such as an actuator endpoint `http://gateway:8080/app1/management/info`) it will fail.  You can still make the request directly to the microservice if you needed to.

By default, all paths are open to any microservice.  To secure your apps, you will need to add your microservices to the list and set the accessible endpoints.

In summary, this config lets you reduce the attack surface of your microservices.  Here's a link to the [related JHipster issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2954) where this was added.  You can also find details in JHipster's [Gateway documentation](http://www.jhipster.tech/api-gateway/#acl).

Comment: How can I add all subpaths? for ex, `jhipster.gateway.authorized-microservices-endpoints.app1: /api/app1/**` doesnt work.

Comment: You shouldn't include `app1` in the path, it is not present in the microservice endpoint request mapping

Comment: Youre right. I was using a bad example for my question.